# Custom Data Annotations with Repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, repository, data-annotations

I am trying to create my own custom data annotations.  I created a new project and the data annotations work perfectly in this clean project but it doesn't seem to work with my Repository-Pattern project.

I have created a MustBeTrue validation, meaning, the method checks to see if a given checkbox is checked (terms and conditions).

```
[Display(Name = "I accept the terms and conditions")]
[MustBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "Please accept terms and conditions before 
public bool AcceptTerms { get; set; }
//non-relevant properties follow
//....method listed below

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class MustBeTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value != null && value is bool && (bool)value;
    }
}
```

I have this exact same piece of code in a seperate project, created a view and used this model, validation works perfectly.  However, when trying to replicate it in my other project, which uses a repository instead of having the model right in the web application, my custom validation does not run.

EDIT:
Another very important thing to add is that I have a helper to display the fields particular to that entity, eg, I'm using `MvcHtmlString` to return a string of the fields that need to be filled out.

Are there any settings I must check before giving up on this? Is there anything by "default" that should hook up my custom annotations that I haven't done?

NOTE: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations work fine in my repository project, it's only custom ones I can't get to work.

Thanks for any help! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: SOLVED: Problem lies in using HTML helpers to bring back the data inputs (where the MvcHtmlString was returned).  Haven't figured out how to make them work on this scenario